# Django URL Namespace: Do All URLs Require Prefixes?

Tags: python, django

I created a URL namespace by specifying `app_name` in the app's URL module. However, now I am getting a NoReverseMatch error when using a named URL in my template without the namespace prefix.

Is the namespace prefix required for all URLs if one is specified (even if there is no ambiguity)?

Comment: yes u need to specify which url from what app you are using like this ```namespace:url_name```

Comment: @MohammadHusseinRostami thanks for the response. unfortunate that this is not optional.